# Dynamically hide rows in an NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

Is it possible to dynamically hide rows in a table view without reloading everything? I have a (view based) table view with it's content member bound to an array controller (arrangedObjects) which itself gets its content from Core Data.

To enrich the UI I show group rows for sections with the same date (all entries in this set have a date in this case). But for certain tasks I need to hide these group rows (e.g. when sorting for something else but the date). In order to show them I already have to create a copy of the original data set and manually insert entries that serve as placeholders for the group rows (which is annyoing as it duplicates data), but I don't want to re-construct this constantly depending on whether the group rows must be shown or not. Is there a better way for this?

Comment: Filtering an array controller by `NSPredicate` is very fast. Most of the real time search algorithms use that.

Comment: Dang! Filtering, of course! Do you perhaps also have an idea how to avoid the duplication just to insert group rows? Please post an answer in any case.

Comment: Hiding is not the best practice. Loading new filtered dataset would be suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding any row requires to rearrange the table view content anyway.

Create all rows including group rows and filter the group rows if needed by applying an appropriate filter predicate.